# fseek: what is the meaning of SEEK_SET after SEEK_END?

Tags: c#, c

I'm porting some C code to C#, and I found this sequence

```
fseek(fsource, 0L, SEEK_END);
fseek(fsource, 2368, SEEK_SET);
```

I'm trying to understand what is its meaning to rewrite it as a `Stream.Seek()` call. Does the `SEEK_END` call influence the `SEEK_SET`? If not, why is it there?

Edit: to clarify, there is no code in-between these calls that would exploit the position set by `SEEK_END`. My question is about side-effects that would influence the second call.

Comment: Seems redundant. If I had to guess, the second is an old line of someone guessing where the end of the file is, and the first line is the proper call, or the first line is supposed to be `ftell` and then you would use that in `fseek`. You really shouldn't hardcode numbers into the offset of  a  `fseek`.call.

Comment: [From the documentation](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.9.2p3): "*For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by whence. The specified position is the beginning of the file if whence is SEEK_SET, the current value of the file position indicator if SEEK_CUR, or end-of-file if SEEK_END*"

Comment: If the first line was the proper call it would still not work since the second call would override it. Maybe SEEK_END was not supported by the library implementation (see my answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call to

```
fseek(fsource, 0L, SEEK_END);
```

does *not* have any influence on the call to

```
fseek(fsource, 2368, SEEK_SET);
```

This call is independent and will always set the read pointer of the stream to position 2368 from the beginning of the stream.
Actually using SEEK_END is kind of dangerous since, according to this article http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/, it is not necessarily supported by a library implementation.
I cannot tell you the reason why it is there. It *might* be a workaround for a bug of the original library implementation. According to the standard the call is redundant, though.

Comment: Looking up the standard would tell you why it is there. In fact, the `SEEK_END` operation may be undefined for binary streams, on systems where this difference matters. Otherwise, `SEEK_END` is well defined and meaningful.

Comment: My question was about side-effects on the subsequent call. There is no code in between that would exploit the position set by `SEEK_END`, even if it was defined.